# Проверка(папки) на придел файлов в папке

Tags: c#

При копирование нужно сделать проверку (*когда файлы копируются в папку*) папки на определенный лимит в **100МБ**, если папка превышает размер в **100МБ** ( допустим **101 МБ**) выйти из цикла.

Код:

```
public static string GooVer = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
public static void GetFilesList()
    {
        string[] extens = { ".txt", ".doc", ".cs",  ".ico", ".Dll", ".Html", ".Htm", ".Xml", ".Php", ".png" };
        long DS = 1000000;
        foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(GooVer, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            if (DirSize(new DirectoryInfo(Easy.GooVer), DS) > DS)
            {
                string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                if (Array.IndexOf(extens, ext) >= 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        File.Copy(fileName, Path.Combine(Easy.str1, Path.GetFileName(fileName)), true);
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static long DirSize(DirectoryInfo d, long aLimit = 0)
    {
        long Size = 0;
        FileInfo[] fis = d.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo fi in fis)
        {
            Size += fi.Length;
            if (aLimit > 0 && Size > aLimit)
                return Size;
        }
        DirectoryInfo[] dis = d.GetDirectories();
        foreach (DirectoryInfo di in dis)
        {
            Size += DirSize(di, aLimit);
            if (aLimit > 0 && Size > aLimit)
                return Size;
        }
        return (Size);
    }
```

Не могу добиться ожидаемого результата!

**P.S: NetFramework 2.0**

Comment: Подумал что лучше создать новую тему с обновлённым кодом)

Comment: В прошлом вопросе вам дали рабочий код, а ваш код снова делает полную херню. Вы зачем то считаете размер рабочего стола, а не папки в которую копируете, дальше код можно даже не читать, он 100% работает не правильно

Comment: И да, `1000000` - это только 1мб, а не 100мб. Добавьте ещё пару нулей.

Comment: @Monk, В прошлом вопросе, я пробовал делать как было сказано иным пользователем! Но у  меня не работало, приведите вы свой код, если у Вас работает, может я и вправду где-то намудрил, потому что испробовал много вариантов. У Вас получилось добиться лимита копирования файлов и завершить цикл копирование когда папка выше `100МБ` ?

Comment: Уточните - которая папка? Из которой вы копируете или в которую вы копируете? В этой папке, которая ограничена 100мб, могут уже быть файлы или она создается прямо перед копированием?

Comment: @Monk, В которую копирую, ну сначала я создаю папку, после запускаю метод копирования файлов из всех папок.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50970/discussion-between-artes-and-monk).

Comment: @ArteS я вам там в первом вашем вопросе добавил ответ (др.вариант решения), правда код не соответствует NetFramework 2.0, ну вы уж там сами скорректируете...)